# Testcafe takes about 2 minutes everytime to trigger the browser. What could be the fix here?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-testing

I have node 12.14.0, npm 6.13.4 and testcafe 1.7.1 in my Windows 10 PC.

I am trying to run a basic sample script using the command **testcafe chrome test1.js**:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
    // Test code
});
```

It takes about 2 minutes everytime for the browser to be triggered.  The test runs fine after that though.

What could be causing this delay?  I also tried running it through npm command and got the same result.

Comment: Could you please clarify if this issue occurs with other browsers? Also, I suggest you run Chrome as a [portable browser](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#portable-browsers) by the full path: `testcafe "path:\`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\`" test.js`

Comment: Yes, it was occurring with other browsers too.  the full path didn't work either.  But downgrading the testcafe version to 1.6.1 fixed the problem (atleast for now).  I will post back if i find anything else.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Try disabling the antiviral software if you have any when you start TestCafe and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried turning off the antivirus software with Testcafe 1.7.1 but no luck.  With Testcafe 1.6.1, it is running fine.

Comment: Until now, our attempts to replicate this issue were unsuccessful. Only the very first browser start can be slowed down, but it works quickly after all. You might want to try disabling firewall and other similar protection tools if you have any.

Comment: I've found the same issue, when I found this post I tried downgrading to 1.6.1 and my tests started in about 10s, vs 2min + for any version/latest above that. Janaaaa, did you find a resolve for this?

Comment: @Jamie Kemp Could you please share the full command line with which you start your tests? Also, I'd appreciate it if you capture a video during the test launching process with the Task Manager window opened (to see the CPU usage of processes). This will help us determine the cause of the issue.